# s=10 for i in range(1,11): global s s = s+i print(s)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
s=10
for i in range(1,11):
    global s
    s = s+i
    print(s)
```

here is my error:

```
  File "/home/ashik/PycharmProjects/shafat/test.py", line 3
    global s
    ^
SyntaxError: name 's' is assigned to before global declaration
```

Comment: this is a warning on python 3.5, not an error. Move global declaration up, that should solve it.

Comment: Not in function

Comment: then you don't need global

Answer (score 0):

You should use global s before the value assign in s. You can follow the following code.

```py
global s
s=10
for i in range(1,11):
    s = s+i
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `global` declaration:

```
s=10
for i in range(1,11):
    s = s+i
    print(s)
```

`global` isn't necessary when you don't have a function. When you do use functions, you should avoid `global` anyways because it can cause hard-to-find bugs.